# CountIfs in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, countif

I'm currently trying to replicate the following from Excel into Python:

IF(COUNTIFS(W4, "*multif*", V4, "*conversation*") + COUNTIFS(W4, "*ETF*", V4, "*conversation*"), 1,0)

I'm able to do one of the COUNTIFS using the following code (This would be the COUNTIFS(W4, "*multif*", V4, "*conversation*") section) :

```
def countifs2(df, col, parameter,col2, parameter2, new_name):
df[new_name] = 0
df.loc[df[col].str.contains(parameter, na=True)
       & df[col2].str.contains(parameter2, na=True),
       new_name] = 1
return df
```

How can I create the replica of the earlier Excel function where I look at two COUNTIFS, if one of them is true, then return 1?

My current code is:

```
def ORcountifs2(df, col, parameter,col2, parameter2, col3, parameter3, col4, parameter4, new_name):
df[new_name] = 0
df.loc[[df[col].str.contains(parameter, na=True)
       and df[col2].str.contains(parameter2, na=True)] 
       or 
       [df[col3].str.contains(parameter3, na=True)
       and df[col4].str.contains(parameter4, na=True)]  ,
       new_name] = 1
return df
```

Example in Excel:

[image]

If (column B contains "hello" AND column C contains "bat") OR (column B contains "hel" AND column D contains "df")

This new column would be True, False, False since the first row satisfies the second part of the OR statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Your original formula doesn't make sense - are you missing a comma/equal sign in there or something?

Comment: Sorry my bad, there should be a comma before the 1. Just edited it in. Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please edit your post and include the code as text.

Comment: Just edited and included code as text

Comment: @user3085496 You shouldn't rely on a True/False result when working with COUNTIFS or SUMIFS, that should at least be `=IF(COUNTIFS(W4, "multif", V4, "conversation") + COUNTIFS(W4, "ETF", V4, "conversation") > 0, 1,0)` - although this may have nothing to do with your actual issue, I just wanted to point that out :)